# How to divide 1 column into 5 segments with pandas and python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a list of 1 column and 50 rows.
I want to divide it into 5 segments. And each segment has to become a column of a dataframe. I do not want the NAN to appear (figure2). How can I solve that?
Like this:
[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(result_list)

AWA=df[:10]
REM=df[10:20]
S1=df[20:30]
S2=df[30:40]
SWS=df[40:50]

result = pd.concat([AWA, REM, S1, S2, SWS], axis=1)
result
```

Figure2
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function:

```
result_list = [i for i in range(50)]
pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(result_list, (10, 5), order='F'))
Out: 
   0   1   2   3   4
0  0  10  20  30  40
1  1  11  21  31  41
2  2  12  22  32  42
3  3  13  23  33  43
4  4  14  24  34  44
5  5  15  25  35  45
6  6  16  26  36  46
7  7  17  27  37  47
8  8  18  28  38  48
9  9  19  29  39  49
```

Comment: A small change in the order of elements - `pd.DataFrame(np.array(result_list).reshape(5, 10).T)`

Comment: @NickilMaveli Ah yes I didn't pay attention to the order. Thanks!